# Is my flag review count notification bugged?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reviewing

For the past few days now, I've noticed that my flag counter next to the review queue hasn't been functioning properly. Currently, it's showing there are 5 flags awaiting review: [image: flag notification]

However, when I view the flags, I'm only shown 1 or 2. Upon flagging/reviewing those 1 or 2 things, the counter would normally drop to show that there are fewer flags waiting to be reviewed. This isn't the case. It still shows 5 flags, but when I click to review it, the page is empty.

I use Chrome, in case it has something to do with that. Although @Sterno confirms it occurs in IE too.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Hm. I can see 5, so it might just be you.

Comment: I have the same issue: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1YBKh.png. It's been going on for at least a few days. (Chrome & IE on PC, but it also occurs on my iPad).

Comment: I show 2 right now, but only one question. Interestingly, there are 2 flags on that one question (`not an answer x2`). The flag count seems to now be how many flags there are, not how many flagged questions there are to review. I suspect this is part of a change in progress. (Firefox here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The explicit count of review tasks was removed from the top bar. Instead, we get a red dot on the top bar when there are many things to review, and grey dots in the menu when there are only a couple::

[image: Red and grey dots in review menu]